# A question about route definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have defined the resources in *routes.rb*

```
resources :cars
```

In my view (index.html.haml), I defined a link for deleting one item:

```
%td
  =link_to(t("delete"), car_post_path(car))
```

I got the NoMethodError:
**undefined method `car_post_path'**

Why? (I am using Rails 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to delete a car object, instead of a post object which belongs to a car, right?

If this is true, you should use `car_path(car)` instead of `car_post_path(car)`

There are two ways to do so:

```
# 1
%td= link_to t("delete"), car_path(car), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete

# 2
%td= link_to t("delete"), car, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete
```

As this is a RESTful resource, in #2 passing the `car` object with `:method => :delete` would be enough to tell rails to use `car_path(car)`. So these two have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'DELETE', car, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Please go through [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code into the following

> %td
>   =link_to(t("delete"),
>   car_path(car))

since u didnt associating any relation with ruote as for ur code. so check with it..

Answer (score 0):

I see other good answer to this question. I just want to add that if you want to list the routes define in your application you should launch:

```
...$ rake routes
```

from the command line and get something like

```
        speakers GET    /speakers(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"speakers"}
                 POST   /speakers(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"speakers"}
     new_speaker GET    /speakers/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"speakers"}
    edit_speaker GET    /speakers/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"speakers"}
         speaker GET    /speakers/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"speakers"}
                 PUT    /speakers/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"speakers"}
                 DELETE /speakers/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"speakers"}
```

so if you do suffix with `_path` or `_url` (for instance) `edit_speaker` you will obtain  `edit_speaker_path` or `edit_speaker_url` that are the callable methods names of your routes.